# Concatenating dynamic number of matched values

Tags: excel

In Excel, if I have A1:E1 and A2:E2 containing matched values (i.e., A1-A2) and wish to join these along with some other standard text, is there an easy way to do this?  Note that not there may be 1-5 pairs of matched values.

For example:

[image]

would result in "(if y==4)*50 + (if y==6)*50 + (if y==9)*50"

AND

[image]

would result in "(if y==2)*50 + (if y==3)*25"

I've look at concat, textjoin, and other text functions but have no come up with a clean way to do this.  I do NOT want to use VBA, rather do this entirely within Excel's cells.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dynamic method of selecting the correct cell range.

The `INDEX` function can help you.  This can also be done with `INDIRECT` but, unlike `INDEX`, it would be volatile, and could signicantly slow down your spreadsheet.

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,"(if y==" & INDEX(1:1,1,1):INDEX(1:1,1,COUNTA(1:1)) & ")*" & INDEX(2:2,1,1):INDEX(2:2,1,COUNTA(1:1)))
```

or, a little shorter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,"(if y==" & A1:INDEX(1:1,1,COUNTA(1:1)) & ")*" & A2:INDEX(2:2,1,COUNTA(1:1)))
```

[image]